"Infinite-dimensional Courant–Fischer"
Let $T$ be a positive self-adjoint operator, possibly unbounded, on a Hilbert space with domain $D$ and spectrum $\sigma(T)$. I know that
$$\inf\sigma(T)=\inf\limits_{\substack{x\in D\\\|x\|=1}}\langle x,Tx\rangle;$$
in a sense it is an infinite-dimensional version of the Courant–Fischer min-max principle, but is meaningfully different. I cannot find a name or reference for this result and would like to cite it. Does anyone know if it is named, or of a reference text where it appears?

The bounded case is in Evans, Partial Differential Equations, first Lemma in appendix D.6

The unbounded case is in another book of Evans. Note that your question is equivalent to
\begin{align}
\inf\ \sigma(T) = \inf\ W(T), 
\end{align}
where $W(T):=\{(Tx,x) \mid x \in \mathcal{D},\ \|x\|=1\}$ denotes the so-called numerical range. This equation is proved for (possibly unbounded) self-adjoint operators $T$ in Evans, Spectral Theory and Differential Operators, Theorem 4.4. in Chapter 3 (note that in this book the numerical range is denoted differently by $\Theta(T)$). But I never heared that this result has a name.
